# Python Comparar lista de meses com a da base e mostrar as duas

Tags: python

Tenho uma lista de meses de janeiro a dezembro. Tenho uma outra lista que tem o mês e um valor. Por exemplo:

```
Jan = 12.00

Fev = 15.00

Ago = 10.00
```

Quero exibir o ano todo e mostrar todos os meses. Os meses que não tem valor nenhum devem aparecer como 0.

Comment: Poste seu código, fica mais fácil para ajudar vc.

Comment: É uma lista ou um dicionário?

Comment: Essa lista dos meses que tenho é um dicionario meses = [Jan,Fev...] .. e a outra lista é resultado de uma consulta, se tem tem o valor ele exibe o mês

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponho que seja algo desse tipo:

```
meses = ['jan', 'fev', 'mar', 'abr', 'mai', 'jun', 'jul', 
                         'ago', 'set', 'out', 'nov', 'dez']

valores = {'jan' : 12, 'fev' : 15, 'ago' : 10}

for mes in meses:
    if mes in valores:
        v = valores.get(mes)
    else:
        v = 0

    print(mes + " " + str(v))
```

Comment: valeu isso mesmo! Obriagdo Pedro